# AWS Python StepFunctions stepfunctions.steps.Parallel [Generate Definition]

Tags: python, parallel-processing, aws-step-functions

is there an example of the Python AWS Data Science SDK for stepfunctions stepfunctions.steps.Parallel class implementation?
Parallel execution requires branches, but i cant seem to find the methods or documentation about their description.

Generating a synchronous list of steps works fine, but i cant find how to define the parallel step, anyone knows?
Are there any other libraries that can do this? boto3 as far as i looked doesnt have the functionality and CDK is not suitable, as this will be a service.

I'd like to be able to generate something like this by using just code:

```
{
  "Comment": "Parallel Example.",
  "StartAt": "LookupCustomerInfo",
  "States": {
    "LookupCustomerInfo": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "End": true,
      "Branches": [
        {
         "StartAt": "LookupAddress",
         "States": {
           "LookupAddress": {
             "Type": "Task",
             "Resource":
               "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:AddressFinder",
             "End": true
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "StartAt": "LookupPhone",
         "States": {
           "LookupPhone": {
             "Type": "Task",
             "Resource":
               "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:PhoneFinder",
             "End": true
           }
         }
       }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Boto3 definitely can do that, boto does not care about the inner workings of the service, you basically pass boto the step function definition and thats it. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.create_state_machine

Comment: but i want to generate the definition, its not static and will change based on input

Comment: I'd look at json generation as a last resort. This data science SDK pretty much does what i need, its just the lack of documentation on parallel processing thats missing

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-step-functions-data-science-sdk-python/blob/main/src/stepfunctions/steps/states.py#L484 does not suffice? There you have your `Parallel` on which you probably have to call `add_branch` a couple of times.